# Shape with increasing width

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I would like to create a shape, which starts with a certain width and then increases to the end. Currently I have this shape here:

[image]

Generated by this [document](http://dabblet.com/gist/5466567). How can I style the shape, that it starts with width **x** and gets bigger and bigger until it reaches widtht **y**?

Besides that, is it also possible to simply rotate a shape with CSS?

Comment: this may help you http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with `CSS3` [Animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) and [Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp):

Heres an example I made which makes the shape grow in width and spin around endlessly:

**[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/5466731)**

Heres a demo showing how you can make the shape grow until a certain width is met:

**[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/5466899)**

Comment: That was very helpful so far. With respect ot the width I have misformulated my question. I didn't mean the `width` property per ses, but the height in this case. I don't want this as a transition, but as a fixed shape. Currently, I am playing with the border-radius property to get the effect I want, but maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: That's alright, hope this could be of some help in the future. So basically you're wanting the shapes height / (width?) to change, when you hover over, or by itself?

Comment: This shouldn't be something that changes on event, the shape I want is supposed to be fixed. If I set the height to value **x** then this is the height throughout the whole shape, but it should have a different height at the end of the shape (from left to right)

Comment: This would be very hard to do with `css`, this is the closest I could come: http://dabblet.com/gist/5467101 I'd personally recommend using and image. hope this helps.